# Cannot create ad hoc app in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to create IPA in xcode 6 to publish app on app store but it is giving certificate validation error and not allowing me to proceed. Please guide me with this.

Comment: CAn you please post the exact message that you are receiving, thanks.

Comment: "Your account already has a valid certificate" dialog appears everytime when i tried to create ipa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For publishing to app store make sure

1. The certificate you are using iOS Distribution Certificate.
2. The provisioning profile assosiated with the certificate is App store provisioning profile.
3. The Bundle ID of you app must match to the one define in provisioning profile.
4. The status of app in the itunes connect should be ""Waiting for upload".
5. The version number of the app defined in itunes connect must be same as that defined in xcode.